# Passing a list to another Form but can't get values from it

Tags: c#, winforms

I am passing a list to another form, but I can't get get the index of the `Form`.

I've tried to use LINQ, but it's not working. I am able to see the id and name of my passed list, but I can't extract the id!

```
private void btnWeiter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListData data = new ListData();
    int id = data.id;
    var abc=lookUpEditMain.GetSelectedDataRow();
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    list.Add(abc);
    frmBudget frm = new frmBudget(list,id);
    frm.Show();
}
```

That's in `Form1`!
In `Form2` I have:

```
public frmBudget(List<object> liste, int id)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    list = liste;

    test();
}
```

I am actually getting the list passed, also right filled. I have the index 0 where id and name is stored.

When I try to obtain the id through

```
var ids = list[0];
```

I am not getting the id only which I need for :

```
string query = string.Format("Select id,name from x where y in ({0})", string.Join(",", ids));
```

I hope you can help me out.

**Basically:**
I just need to extract the id from my lookupedit from form1 and give it to form2. So the form2 will show me the right stuff in the lookupedit.

Comment: Since you have `List<object>`, to use `string.Join` you need to use `ToString()`: `string query = string.Format("Select id,name from x where y in ({0})", string.Join(",", list.Select(x => x.ToString()));`.

Comment: Pass around a strongly-typed list.

Comment: `var ids = list[0]` sets `ids` to the _first element in `list`_. You probably wanted `string.Join(",", list)` @TetsuyaYamamoto `string.Join` does a `ToString()` itself

Comment: my problem is, if i chose the index [0], there is an id and a name inside. so basically i am not receiving the id. I am getting something like "Select id,name from x where y in (Wizard.frmMain+ListData)"

Comment: What is the type of `abc`? Why is the list's element type `object` instead of the actual type of the elements?

Comment: var abc is filled with the selected lookupedit  ( it have to be a type of object). There is an id  and a name inside. So i pass it to an object list

Comment: @Arti - Don't ever use `List<object>`. You should always use strong-typing or (at a last resort) `List<dynamic>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity ok i changed it all to dynamic. But how do i retrieve only one element of my index [0]? I have an id in there + a name i just need the id

Comment: var BSid = from emp in list select emp.id; that fixed it for me

Comment: @Arti - And there's `dynamic` in action.

Answer (score 0):

Use simply property to pass data from Form1 to Form2

Form1

```
    private void btnWeiter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Form2 frm = new Form2())
        {
            List<object> list = new List<object>();
            // Pass the list to the Form2 property
            frm.listFromForm1 = list;
            // Open Form2
            frm.Show();
        }
    }
```

Form2

```
    // Public property what passed from Form1
    public List<object> listFromForm1 { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Now you can handle any details of list

    }
```